# esbuild is not compiling imported modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, esbuild

I am trying to compile a very simple typescript code with [esbuild](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild).

However `esbuild` is compiling only the entry file.

This is my setup:

```typescript
//index.ts
import * as mod1 from './mod1';
mod1.my_method();
```

```typescript
//mod1.ts
export function my_method(){
  console.log('debug');
}
```

I run:

```
esbuild index.ts --outdir=./dist --platform=node
```

the compilation is done with no error and if I now check the `dist` I get only

```
dist
- index.js
```

```js
// dist/indes.js
import * as mod1 from './mod1';
mod1.my_method();
```

but there is no trace of `dist/mod1.js`. So of course the code cannot run and give an error.

Why `esbuild` is not compiling all the other files like `mod1.ts`?

I can't use `--bundle` in my project.

Comment: Well --bundle option it is what you have to do in order to compile also imported modules. "I can't use --bundle in my project." it is like you would say "I want to bundle but I cannot".  
https://esbuild.github.io/api/#bundle
.

Answer (score -2):

esbuild index.ts --outdir=./dist --platform=node
^^^

you only specify the index.ts file in the commandline

i never actually worked with esbuild, but there is probably a function for folders, like `esbuild . --outdir=./dist --platform=node`

Comment: But I don't want to import the whole folder. I need to import only the required files.

Comment: then maybe add both files to the arguments, `esbuild index.ts mod1.ts ...`

Comment: My project is more complex than that. It has hundreds of files.

Comment: well... either use the entire folder with all the files inside or just add each file by itself
`esbuild 1.ts 2.ts 3.ts ...`